# absolute positioning on Ipad

Tags: html, css, ipad

I'm working in a web site, but it's the first time that a client ask me for ipad compatibility. So I started to work like usual but at the moment to see the result on the ipad  there are some objects that i can't put in the correct position.

I already tried to change all my absolute positioning with margins and paddings, but this part(image above) does not work, when i change the position the content stay in the same place.

[image: Content Open]
[image: Content Closed]

The [current web site](http://www.manedelaparra.com/html/)
The current [css](http://www.manedelaparra.com/html/css/index.css)

But the important part is here:

```
<div id="super-wrapper">
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- Some Divs -->

  <div id="content" class="open">

    <!--This menu will be hidden -->
    <ul id="navigation-fans">
        <li id="registrate"><span>Registrate</span></li>
        <li id="crea-club"><span>club</span></li>
        <li id="conoce-clubs"><span>clubs</span></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="close-open" class="open"></div>
    <div id="title"></div>
    <div id="real-content"></div>
  </div>
<!-- Some Divs -->
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapper{
  width:1024px;
  height:768px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position:relative;
  background: url(../../pics/1.jpg) no-repeat;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#content{
  background-image:url('../images/secciones_fondo.png');
  height:423px;
  width:1024px;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  right:-374px;
  padding-top:1px;
  margin-top:143px;
}

/* This is the position of #content when is open */
element.style {
    right: -374px;
}
```

## Update

I found that the problem is jplayer, but i still don't know wich is the real problem, by the moment i disable it and it works.

Comment: Does it work in Safari on a desktop computer? I've never had any issues with this sort of thing with the iPad.

Comment: @RichBradshaw Yes it works perfectly, it's just on the ipad,iphone :s

Answer (score 0):

it might be your `super-wrapper` tag that you are not assigning correct properties to. If you look at the code, `super-wrapper` is essentially holding the same as `wrapper`, correct? If so, `wrapper` could be inheriting properties from `super-wrapper` which you might not be what you want.

Hope this helps.